# Integral of Legendre polynomials $P_n(\cos\theta)$

Tags: definite-integrals, legendre-polynomials

Given the Legendre polynomial $P_n(\cos\theta)$, I would like to calculate the integral:

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}-a}^{\frac{\pi}{2}+a}\,\,P_n(\cos\theta)\sin\theta \,\,d\theta$$

where $a\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.
Any suggestion on how to proceed? If $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$, is it possible to find a closed solution?

Comment: If $a=\pi/2$, the integral is $2\delta_{n0}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Considering the problem of the antiderivative $$I_n=\int
P_n(\cos\theta)\sin\theta \,\,d\theta$$  changing variable $x=\cos(\theta)$, you have $$I_n=-\int P_n(x)\,dx$$ If you look [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LegendreP/21/01/01/0001/), you will notice that $$I_n=-\frac{P_{n+1}(x)-P_{n-1}(x)}{2 n+1}$$

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks! It is clear how to proceed now!